# How to disable the custom keypad key using jquery?

Tags: jquery

HI I am new to jquery mobile. I got a plugin for numeric keypad from the internet and now i want to validate the numeric keypad. (i.e) when the user clicks the + or - button it should be displayed only once and When the user click for second time it should not be displayed .

Here is the link from where i got the plugin http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use conditions on key press.For example:backspace=8.

Comment: Thanks ... Can you explain me more

Comment: http://www.foreui.com/articles/Key_Code_Table.htm.You can see all the key codes here.create an handler for + or - keydown.if any of them is pressed disable or ignore the value of other.

Comment: Sorry I am not ale to open the URL sent by you

Comment: http://www.foreui.com/articles/Key_Code_Table.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you**

```
   function (e, inputElement) {
        // If the user gives the textbox any keyboard input, mark the input box as "dirty"
        var scope = this;
        var k = e.which;

    // Verify that the key entered is not a special key
    if (k == 20 /* Caps lock */
     || k == 16 /* Shift */
     || k == 9 /* Tab */
     || k == 27 /* Escape Key */
     || k == 17 /* Control Key */
     || k == 91 /* Windows Command Key */
     || k == 19 /* Pause Break */
     || k == 18 /* Alt Key */
     || k == 93 /* Right Click Point Key */
     || ( k >= 35 && k <= 40 ) /* Home, End, Arrow Keys */
     || k == 45 /* Insert Key */
     || ( k >= 33 && k <= 34 ) /*Page Down, Page Up */
     || (k >= 112 && k <= 123) /* F1 - F12 */
     || (k >= 144 && k <= 145 )) { /* Num Lock, Scroll Lock */
        return false;
    }
    else {
        scope.setPointValueDirtyStatus(inputElement, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not giving me the solution.